# How to get category name of lucene's SimpleNaiveBayesClassifier?

Tags: solr, lucene, classification, naivebayes

When using lucene's `SimpleNaiveBayesClassifier` the `SimpleNaiveBayesClassifier#assignClass` method returns an `ClassificationResult<BytesRef>`, how can I get the original value of category field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you want:

```
classificationResult.getAssignedClass().utf8ToString()
```